# First-person game in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I know I need to use a frustum projection for a first-person game I'm writing. However, I'm not sure what the most efficient way to move around in the world is.

Currently I'm using

```
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, eyex, eyey, eyez, lookx, looky, lookz, upx, upy, upz);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0);
```

every time the display is redrawn. User input changes the "eye", "look" position vectors, and the "up" direction vector.

However, I've read elsewhere that one should tranlate/rotate the world and not the "camera".

My question is: should I rotate the objects about a fixed "camera" (i.e. only use setLookAtM once at set up) or should I carry on using my current method?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a thing called as camera in OpenGL. In fact, what you describe by moving the objects instead of the viewpoint is what Opengl actually accomplishes internally to give you the feeling that camera moves. There is a great article along with a tutorial that describes all about cameras on OpenGL ES 2 and basically it is the same logic on other versions:

http://db-in.com/blog/2011/04/cameras-on-opengl-es-2-x/

It might seem boring and confusing but I have been searching about cameras on OpenGL ES 2 a lot and this article is almost perfect for a beginner.

To answer your question, your current method is exactly the same that you are describing. The camera is always fixed in OpenGL and what you do with matrix multiplications provides you the effect that you want already. When you multiply your model matrix with view matrix and projection matrix, in the end, you define a new position for your object depending on your camera parameters.